# Sort user reviews based on Windows OS

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have few apps in Windows Store both for `Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 8.`

We have recently released apps for `Windows Phone 8 phone`.When i log in to my developer console, i had user reviews already for Windows Phone 7 device, now how can i sort the user reviews for Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone 7.

And also in my `Windows Phone 7 or Windows Phone 7 phone` for my app the reviews are not showing, but in the developer console the reviews are being shown.

Why so ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the first thing you asked is possible, i think it is only possible to tell the device they are using and country they are in using the code that appears underneath their name next to the review.

As for the second question one solution may be that the person may have reviewed your app in, for example, China. Yet, if you are looking at the reviews in the US store, only reviews made in the US will appear. This could be why some app reviews don't appear except for in your developer console.

Comment: But how can we differenciate that the review was writtern for WP7 app or WP8 app ?

Comment: I don't think thats actually possible, you can gain reports on downloads to see users operating systems and other information but i'm 95% sure you can't do it for reviews unless im missing something